# Can the Top:Bottom Margin or Padding be reduced in the new Top Questions List?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

All, looking at further ways to reduce the real estate required by each question in the new Top Questions list, it seems like there is a lot of excess either margin or padding at the top and bottom of the question. This is causing each question to require more vertical real estate than the Top Questions list before. This translates into much more scrolling being required on laptops to view the Top Questions list.

The problem areas are shown in red in the image below:

[image]

That's a full 8 px on top and 10 px on bottom. Can that be reduced to ~4 px each? That would bring the real estate required of the new list inline with the old and help avoid the additional scrolling required on laptops or small screens where it matters.

Can the top/bottom margin or padding be reduced?

(also, can the name of the author or last editor be in its own `<div>` anchored to the bottom-right of the bounding control so it doesn't move around depending on whether the tittle wraps?)

Thanks for the continued hard work -- it's getting there.

Comment: The `padding-top` and `padding-bottom` values on the `/questions` page, questions with a specific tag pages, and search results pages, which all use the `question-summary` class, are both 12px. The padding on the home page, which uses the `s-post-summary` class, is 16px on all sides. Personally, I find 6px or 4px to be reasonable for those values.